# How to consider next line content with sed search and replace command?

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed, csh

I am trying to replace following pattern

```
  }

  if {[info exists env(PATH)]} {
     tcl::native_code " Message"
     tcl::native_code " Done"
```

with

```
    tcl_block

    if {[info exists env(PATH)]} {
       puts " Message"
       puts " Done"
```

with the help of sed/awk(preferable sed). But not sure how to consider the content of next line content while searching the pattern.

Please help!
BR,
Learner!!

Comment: Can you explain why you need the next line? What rules do you want to use when replacing?

Comment: @choroba, thanks for looking into this. I want to replace curly braces with tcl_code statement only if the next line is if {[info exists env(PATH)]} {. In case if of any other statement, I want to retain the original code as is. Similarly, I am also looking forward to replace tcl::native_code with puts " Message" if it's part of the same section. -BR, Learner!

Comment: How do you define "the same section"?

Comment: @choroba I was meant by next line after if {[info exists env(PATH)]} { line

Comment: But where does the "section" end?

Comment: @choroba -it should either end at } or } else {

Comment: @choroba -Is there a way to read the next line content in sed? If yes, could you please help!

Comment: Perhaps you mean next non-empty line?

Comment: But you want `}` that matches the opening `{`, as I guess the ifs can be nested...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this `sed` with conditions mentioned in your comments.

```
sed '/\}/ {N;N;/if {\[info exists env(PATH)\]} {/ s/\}/tcl_block/};/tcl_block/ {N;N;/tcl/ s/tcl::native_code\|ntcl::native_code/puts/g}' $inputfile
```

**Output**

```
tcl_block

  if {[info exists env(PATH)]} {
     puts  "Message"
     puts  "Done"
```

If you have more `tcl::native_code` lines than the example data, then a complete recode may be needed but to handle it with this current code, add more `N;` lines to take into account for the substitution within the second condition.

```
sed '/\}/ {N;N;/if {\[info exists env(PATH)\]} {/ s/\}/tcl_block/};/tcl_block/ {N;N;N;/tcl/ s/tcl::native_code\|ntcl::native_code/puts/g}' $inputfile
```

Comment: This is truly awesome, thanks a lot. In case, If I also need to check two additional lines                               (i.e. }\ntcl::native_code " ) after tcl::native_code then what would be the addition I should make. Thanks a lot for your great help!!

Comment: @ShikhaRustagi You're welcome. Please check the edit

Comment: --->   sed '/\}/ {N;/if {\[info exist env(PATH)\]} {/ s/\}/s_tcl_block/};/s_tcl_block/ {N;N;/tcl/ s/tcl::native_code/puts/ /\}/ {N;/tcl::native_code.*/ / {/ s/\}/e_end_block/};/e_tcl_block/g}' $filename

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^\s*}/{:a;N;/\n$/ba;/{\[info exists env(PATH)\]}/!{h;s/\(.*\)\n.*/\1/p;g;s/.*\n/\n/;D};s/}/tcl_block/}' file |
sed '/{\[info exists env(PATH)\]}/{:a;n;/\S/{s/tcl::native_code/puts/g;ba}}'
```

The solution is in two parts.

The first part, replaces a leading `}` by `tcl_block` if the next non-empty line contains `{[info exists env(PATH)]}`.

N.B. If the next non-empty line is does not match it is presented again as a possible match for `}`.

The second part, on matching `{[info exists env(PATH)]}`, replaces any occurrences of `tcl::native_code` by `puts` in any following lines up to the end of file or an empty line, which ever comes first.

---

If OP prefers to match from `{[info exists env(PATH)]}` to a closing `}` the second part can be simplified:

```
sed '/{\[info exists env(PATH)\]}/,/}/s/tcl::native_code/puts/g'
```